# MVN test return with errors because of initializing game board

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, testing, javafx

My problem is that mvn test command returns with this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.setGridLinesVisible(boolean)" because "this.gridPane" is null
at stickgame.Controller.GameController.initialize(GameController.java:55)
at
GameLogicTest.setUp(GameLogicTest.java:24)

However, if I run the application it works perfectly. I have no idea why the gridPane variable is null after initializing in the tests.
The rest of the test methods would return with 0, they are would work. Any thoughts?

```
public class GameLogicTest {
    private GameController gameController;
    private GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    private GameState gameState;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        gameController = new GameController();
        gameController.initialize();
        gridPane = gameController.getGridPane();
        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
        gameState = gameController.getGameState();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class GameController {

    private GameState gameState;

    /**
     * Variable to earn the GridPane from the StickGame.fxml file.
     */
    @FXML
    private GridPane gridPane;

    private static final int lineWidth = 100;
    private static final int lineThickness = 6;

    @FXML
    public GridPane getGridPane() {
        return gridPane;
    }

    public GameState getGameState() {
        return gameState;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        gameState = new GameState();

        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(false);
        final int gridHeight = 200;
        final int gridWidth = 200;
        gridPane.setPrefSize(gridHeight, gridWidth);


        for (int row = 0; row < GameState.BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < GameState.BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
                createVerticalLine(row, col);
                createHorizontalLine(row, col);
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < GameState.BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
            int col = GameState.BOARD_SIZE;
            createHorizontalLine(row, col);
        }

        for (int col = 0; col < GameState.BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
            int row = GameState.BOARD_SIZE;
            createVerticalLine(row, col);
        }
        Logger.info("Grid created of lines");
    }
...

public void createHorizontalLine(final int row, final int col) {
        Line line = new Line(0, 0, lineWidth, 0);
        line.setStrokeWidth(lineThickness);
        line.setOnMouseClicked(this::handleLineClick);
        gridPane.add(line, row * 2 + 1, col * 2);
    }

    public void createVerticalLine(final int row, final int col) {
        Line line = new Line(0, 0, 0, lineWidth);
        line.setStrokeWidth(lineThickness);
        line.setOnMouseClicked(this::handleLineClick);
        gridPane.add(line, row * 2, col * 2 + 1);
    }
```

Comment: *"I have no idea why the gridPane variable is null after initializing."* It's not initialized though. The `gridPane` is annotated `@FXML`, which indicates that it is instantiated by the `FXMLLoader` when the FXML file is loaded and then injected into the controller. Instead of instantiating the controller directly (which I don't think you are doing in your application code), load the FXML and retrieve the controller from the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: You should also consider exactly what it is you want to unit test. If you properly separate out the game logic from the UI, then you can unit test the game logic without the UI or the controller at all. You seem to have done a lot of this anyway. Can't you just instantiate `GameState` in your test class and then test it out? For the most part, everything else in the controller is just invoking JavaFX library code, which is tested by the JavaFX developers, not by your unit test.

Comment: I am not sure the following code makes any sense. Methods annotated with `@FXML` are usually handlers. `@FXML
    public GridPane getGridPane() {
        return gridPane;
    }`

Comment: You should probably be using something like [`TestFX`](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX) for `JavaFX` `GUI` testing.